# Program running mkfifo doesn't work

Tags: c, named-pipes, fifo, mkfifo

I'm trying to make a named pipe on c under linux using the mkfifo command. But when I run the program, I either get a "no such file or directory" error or absolutely nothing (console doesn't display anything)

Here is my code :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int create;
//mkfifo("/tmp/myfifo", 0666);
create = mkfifo("tmp/myfifo", 0666);
if (create==-1)
{
    printf("error%s", strerror(errno));
}
char line[MAX_LINE];
int pipe;
pipe = open("/tmp/myfifo", O_WRONLY);
 if (pipe==-1)
 {printf("error");
 }
printf("Enter line: ");
fgets(line, MAX_LINE, stdin);
write(pipe, line, strlen(line));
sleep (100);
close(pipe);
return 0;
}
```

I am still learning, and I don't understand what i'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See [ask], follow the advice and format&indent this mess correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a named pipe to be useful, somebody has to read it and somebody has to write it. Usually this will be 2 separate programs. Your program is the writer. Where is the reader?

If there is no reader, it is normal for the program to block on the `O_WRONLY` open. So when your program appears to be doing nothing, it's really just doing this:

```
pipe = open("/tmp/myfifo", O_WRONLY);
```

which waits for a reader to show up.

In another terminal, run `cat /tmp/myfifo`. The presence of a reader will allow the writer to make progress. Your program will wake up and move on to the `Enter line` prompt, and what you enter will be read by the `cat` and written to the second terminal.

The other problem is an inconsistency in your filenames. In one place you wrote `"tmp/myfifo"` without a leading slash, so you are trying to create the named pipe in a `tmp` directory that is inside the current working directory. If that `tmp` directory doesn't exist, `No such file or directory` will be the result.

Comment: I have a second reader program, running it from another teminal window only does this :
./test2
ttime__vdso_get_?@?@@